# Window navigation using PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

So I have made two screen to navigate, the problem I am facing is the navigation only takes place for three clicks like I click the button on first screen to go to second screen again I click button on second screen to go to first screen and when I click the button now on the first screen the screen disappears instead when it should open the second screen I just cant find out whats wrong with it. Please help me out with this
this is screen1

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys

class Ui1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(Ui1, self).__init__() # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
    uic.loadUi('../ui/Layout1.ui', self) # Load the .ui file

    # for new user button
    self.btn1 = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'pushButton')
    self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.click)

def click(self):
    from integration.layout2 import Ui2
    self.close()
    self.next=Ui2()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui1()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

and for the second screen

```
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets, QtCore
import sys

class Ui2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
       super(Ui2, self).__init__() # Call the inherited classes __init__ method
       uic.loadUi('../ui/Layout2.ui', self) # Load the .ui file

       self.btn1 = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'pushButton')
       self.btn1.clicked.connect(self.click)

   def click(self):
      from integration.layout import Ui1
      self.close()
      self.next=Ui1()

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui2()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: You should take a look at the `QWizard` class

Comment: `QWizard` is really good if I knew it before i would have used it but if you could tell me whats wrong with the above code that would really helpful